# SMS notifications of new version release on github

Tags: git, github, notifications, sms, magento2

I want to track Magento2 new version releases, and I think the best would be to track it from git. When they release new version I would like to get notified. I prefer to get notification to my mobile phone. Are there any tools for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this: https://www.git-notifier.com/

The email notifications are for free, but to send SMS to your mobile it is not for free. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for